# Error during compilation of Magento 2 Incompatible argument type : Required type:

Tags: magento2, theme, di, compiler, compilation

```
Webkul\VendorPos\Model\ResourceModel\Orders\Grid\Collection
Incompatible argument type:
Required type: \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface.
Actual type: \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
```

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        $mainTable,
        $eventPrefix,
        $eventObject,
        $resourceModel,
        \Webkul\Marketplace\helper\Data $mpHelper,
        $model = \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document::class,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) 
{
        parent::__construct(
            $entityFactory,
            $logger,
            $fetchStrategy,
            $eventManager,
            $connection,
            $resource
        );
        $this->_eventPrefix = $eventPrefix;
        $this->_eventObject = $eventObject;
        $this->mpHelper     = $mpHelper;
        $this->_init($model, $resourceModel);
        $this->setMainTable($mainTable);
}
```

File:
**/var/www/html/app/code/Webkul/VendorPos/Model/ResourceModel/Orders/Grid/Collection.php**

```
\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface
```

Comment: add your `__construct()` function code in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question, the constructor you are using missing `ScopeConfigInterface`, because it's using by your parent construct.

Your code:

```
parent::__construct(
    $entityFactory,
    $logger,
    $fetchStrategy,
    $eventManager,
    $connection,
    $resource
);
```

It should be

```
parent::__construct(
    $entityFactory,
    $logger,
    $fetchStrategy,
    $eventManager,
    $scopeConfig,
    $connection,
    $resource
);
```

You will need to add the scope config into your constructor and make it matches what you see in `parent::__construct()`.

Comment: Thank You..it solves my problem..But Again I am getting new error

Comment: Webkul\Marketplace\Model\Order\Pdf\Creditmemo
                Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation. Actual type: \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface; File:
/var/www/html/app/code/Webkul/Marketplace/Model/Order/Pdf/Creditmemo.php


        Webkul\Marketplace\Model\Order\Pdf\Shipment
                Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation. Actual type: \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface; File:
/var/www/html/app/code/Webkul/Marketplace/Model/Order/Pdf/Shipment.php

Comment: If it resolves your problem can you mark it as completed and probably create a new question for your new errors

Comment: ok.I will do it